# Как найти все НЕ "private static final" Logger с помощью regex?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, intellij-idea

У меня большой проект где мне надо изменить все `Logger` на `private static final`. В проекте присутствуют много Logger с различными модификаторами.

Не могу составить негативный regex. Реально ли вообще объяснить с помощью regex что я НЕ хочу найти? Мне нужуен любая декларация `Logger`, но НЕ `private static final Logger`.

Моя попытка https://regex101.com/r/rL7P33/3

```
^\s*(?!private static final) Logger
```

Но он почему-то не нахожит ничего вообще

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы тот кто минусует писал бы за что минусы. Вопрос ясно сформулирован. Я проделал сам работу до вопроса. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось сделать. Ответ:
https://regex101.com/r/rL7P33/4

```
^\s*(?!private static final).* Logger
```